CTRL+F / search string in code of multiple logic app workflows at once
I have an Azure logic-app with a lot of different workflows. One of this workflows interacts with a file at some point.
I want to find all the workflows that interact somehow with that file. One of the way is to open each workflow one after another, navigate to code section and ctrl+f on the code for the filename or the blobname.
Is there a way to apply that ctrl+f search to multiple/all workflows at once (in a same way as VSCode does a search in a entire project) from azure portal or to do that search process more efficiently ?

Download the definitions and throw them in VS Code and search that way.

would  grep  do this for you?

If you want to search all your current logic app standard workflows without downloading all file contents locally, you can use KUDU:
How to open KUDU:

Open CMD
Navigate to wwwroot:
cd site\wwwroot

The command below searches for the term "DHL" within all workfows - these are files named workflow.json. The /s flag ensures that the search is recursive, meaning it looks through all subfolders as well.
findstr /s "DHL" workflow.json



exactly what I was looking for, and good explanations, cheers
